# FQL - Cant' get friend request from fql table

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

i'm trying to get friends request from the table friend_request  using the following request

```
SELECT uid_from FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to="my uid"
```

but i get an empty response even when i got friend request awainting confirmation

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that query on the [FQL query tester tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)?  If that does return values but your application doesn't, then it is probably due to lack of extended permissions.  You would first need to prompt the user for `read_requests` extended permissions.

Note: you can also use where `uid_to = me()` to get the current user.